# How do i do fixed the List view in search bar

Tags: java, android

So, when the app start, it shows correct 
[image]
but when the search bar clicked, it goes like this
[image]
it stacked to the top, and some of the list missing.
How do i fix this ?
this is the xml:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/cari"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:hint="Cari Dokumen"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="449dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cari"
         />
```

Comment: Add the manifest entry of `Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap both your views inside relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cari"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:hint="Cari Dokumen"/>

    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cari"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: oh , one more, how do i hidden the list view, but when the key typed in the search bar, it shows

Answer (score 0):

So I added the both in a linear layout so one always stays beneath the other. Try it and tell me if it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cari"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:hint="Cari Dokumen"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="449dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i try that, but when clicked, the search bar is missing

Comment: If the answer by @Thomas Meinhart doesn't work this adding this to onCreate:

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your [Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) in AndroidManifest.